# macOS Big Sur : dlopen("/usr/lib/libssl.dylib") crashes with "program is loading libcrypto in an unsafe way"

Tags: macos, openssl, macos-big-sur, dlopen, libcrypto

According to [macOS Big Sur 11.0.1 Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/macos-release-notes/macos-big-sur-11_0_1-release-notes) :

> New in macOS Big Sur 11.0.1, the system ships with a built-in dynamic
> linker cache of all system-provided libraries. As part of this change,
> copies of dynamic libraries are no longer present on the filesystem.
> Code that attempts to check for dynamic library presence by looking
> for a file at a path or enumerating a directory will fail. Instead,
> check for library presence by attempting to dlopen() the path, which
> will correctly check for the library in the cache.

I am on M1 macOS Big Sur 11.1, and there is no file at `/usr/lib/libssl.dylib` :

```
$ ls /usr/lib/libssl.dylib
ls: /usr/lib/libssl.dylib: No such file or directory
```

So I assume `libssl.dylib` is in the linker cache, however
this simple program:

```
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("Calling dlopen()..\n");
    void* handle = dlopen("/usr/lib/libssl.dylib", RTLD_NOW );
    if (handle == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open libssl.dylib: %s\n", dlerror());
        return 1;
    }
    if (dlclose(handle) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not close libssl.dylib: %s\n", dlerror());
        return 1;
    }
    printf("Success!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

compiled with

```
cc -g -o test_load load.c -ldl
```

crashes:

```
$ ./test_load
Calling dlopen()..
WARNING: /Users/hakonhaegland/test/test_load is loading libcrypto in an unsafe way
[1]    9364 abort      ./test_load
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot load the system's libssl because it does not have a stable ABI.

If you go in your `Console > Crash Reports` you'll see an abort log.

> Invalid dylib load. Clients should not load the unversioned libssl dylib as it does not have a stable ABI.